# Skype for Business vacation integration with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: integration

We have Skype for Business 2013 and Sharepoint 2013. We would like to give a user status "On Vacation" and purple color when that user is on vacation. The dates should be taken from intranet vacation system which is based on Sharepoint 2013. Has anybody implemented similar functionality or have an idea how to do it?